# Keeping track of time per developer per task using TFS

Tags: time-management, tracking

I am a 2 month old PM came out as a developer. One thing that I am facing issues here in my company is how to keep track of time per task per developer. Like we are using TFS and we are creating BLI (Back Log Items/Tasks) etc. Plus we are using ClickTime (Online software for billing and tracking time in projects).

Now when I see this as a developer stand of point, I am like this is PIA. 2 time tracking systems...DARN !!!

I am trying to push my team into TFS and updating it to sharepoint. Which is working great so far. How should I link it to my MS Project? Or will MS Project really be helping me in this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks as if you are asking two questions, one being how to link TFS with MS Project, and one about how to keep track of time using TFS. Can you clarify a little further, e.g. by putting more structure into your question or splitting where appropriate? That way you'd increase your chances to get good answers.

Comment: @Raj If you clarify further I would bet you will get some helpful answers, as your other questions have provided you with some as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our project manager does the following:

1. Write a query to filter tasks/stories in TFS
2. Export results into Excel
3. Run statistics on the spreadsheet.

Have you considered this option? I'll speak to our project manager to get more details, but I'm fairly certain that we are now moving away from TFS.

Comment: BTW What was good when using TFS?

Answer (score 0):

I think the two topics go along together quite well. Project (especially Project Server) deals with 'remaining work' and 'completed work'. Project Server integrates with TFS, and these two fields can be custom configured in TFS (some work item templates already contain these) and integrated into Project Server. 
About time tracking, check out http://www.tfs-timetracker.com. It is fully integrated into TFS, allows tracking directly against workitems and offers data export as well as automatic filling of the fields mentioned above.
TFS, Project Server and TFS Timetracker so perfectly integrate into each other so that the developer has great orientation and instant analytics, plus project manager have all times based on rules automatically reported back into MS Project.

Comment: Hi Marc, if you have any relationship with tfs-timetracker, you should add a disclaimer into your answer.